# Mobile_Detect Library Simplify

Tags: php, android, mobile, detect

I am using `Mobile_Detect library` since a long time from https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect. Its detection works fine as long it is updated, but it isn't up to date. Last update was 1 year ago, so I want to simplify detection  without any updates needed, but want to continue using `Mobile_Detect library`. The basic device detection of this library is okay.

Mobile_Detect library uses device names in user agent to detect a device. Is a device missing it fails or detect a tablet as mobile phone. For testing I used a `simple PHP / .htaccess` detection function that works similiar to `Mobile_Detect library`, but this function doesn't check device names in UA. I only look for:

```
Android|Mobile == isMobile (Phone)

Android|!Mobile == isTablet
```

It is based on Google's way to detect Android devices:

https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/user-agent

I tested it over month and with millions of UA checks without any wrong detection.

What I need is a modification of `Mobile_Detect library` that works like my detection. I already tried it with countless methods, but it doesn't work. Does anybody know how to modify the `Mobile_Detect library`?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. It is simple, but it works perfect for mobile device detection.

```
class Mobile_Detect {

function isMobile() {
    $uagent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $mobile_device = false;
    if (preg_match("/(android|mobile|silk|ipad|iphone|ipod)/i", $uagent)) {
        $mobile_device = true;
    }
    return $mobile_device;
}

public function isTablet() {
    $uagent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $tablet = false;
    if (!preg_match("/(mobile)/i", $uagent)) {
        if (preg_match("/(android|silk|touch)/i", $uagent)) {
            $tablet = true;
        }
    }
    if (preg_match("/(mac|ipad)/i", $uagent)) {
        if (!preg_match("/(iphone|ipod)/i", $uagent)) {
            $tablet = true;
        }
    }
    return $tablet;
}

}

$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

if ($detect->isMobile()) {
    if ($detect->isTablet()) {
        echo 'Tablet';
    } else {
        echo 'Mobile';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Desktop';
}
```